# how to select the right div in javascript using parent/child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, html

I have a couple different divs that all look about like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(".show").parent().(".text").toggle();
  });
});

<div class="container #{i}">
    <div class="show">
        show
    </div>

    <div class="text">
        text text text
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to click show, and have it only toggle the text div within its container div. I thought I could grab the parent of the element with class "show" I clicked on, which would be container + index, and then get the child class called "text" in that container div.

This honestly feels fairly trivial, but I'm not very experienced in Javascript yet, and I wasn't sure of the wording to search for. I would greatly appreciate any help. :)

Comment: Use: `$(this).parent().find(".text").toggle();`

Comment: Do `$(this).next().toggle()` instead of `$('.show').parent().('.text').toggle()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is find function for that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".text").toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `siblings` function to get / filter elements on the same level:

```
jQuery('.show').click( function () {
   jQuery(this).siblings('.text').toggle(); 
});
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, you just need to call "find" on the parent and replace the `.show` selector for `this` since you only want to toggle the `.text` divs inside the current (this) parent and not across the board. So you need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".text").toggle(); //replaced .show for this
  });
});
```

Or another alternative (although someone else already posted it)

```
$(".show").siblings(".text").toggle();
```

However, for the above to work, both divs (.show and .text) must be at the same level whereas `find`, will find it even if `.text` is nested inside another element.

Comment: :) exactly what I did -- and thanks for the clarification! I didn't know about siblings before, but I had simplified the code I posted, so they weren't actually at the same level

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to grab the parent...

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle()
});
```

should work. Just grabs the sibling.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this inside .click function

```
$(this).parent().find("text").toggle();
```